# what to do to begin my c# uwp animation in onclik?

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

my code in xml is self explanatory to the seniors in uwp
Unsccestful search of several hours in inet
and very few and complex (beyond my need) animation/layout/components found
its a simple qwestion but i am to totally unable to seize this problem
tried  and so but no way to get the thing working

`<Page
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="800" Height="800" >

<Page.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="mibrush">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>

    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="btnbrush">
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    

</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource mibrush}" BorderThickness="10">



    <Button x:Name="miboton" Content="Button"  Click="Button_Click"  Height="150" 
Margin="444,598,0,0"  Width="200">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="buttonAnimation"  x:Name="buttonAnimation">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="miButton" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="200" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="True"  
/>
            </Storyboard>


        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</Page>

now my cs part of the mainpage

namespace App3{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        buttonAnimation.Begin();
        
          
    }

}
}


crash componets with  not installed exception.i can do keyframes animation,an other ones
but the book treats this chapters as standalone not telling me where to start a how to start animations .
In fact i have to idea how to treat event simplest tiggers of animations.Pls some patience with me im nooby in this language.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `TargetName` and `Button Name`.

These two should be the same.

```
<Button x:Name="miboton"
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="miButton"
```